# SSR rendering save bundle on CDN

Tags: reactjs, web, cdn, server-side-rendering

I have a react web app which is using SSR to serve the bundle to browser on page request.

My question is can I save the bundle over the CDN so that the page request is served from CDN and loaded in browser?

Is it first of all a good practice to cache the bundle on CDN?

Also how the CDN will come to know that I have updated the code do I need to deliberately invalidate the CDN cache?